# Swift 2.0 Parse PFFile/Image

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, pffile

I have a Swift project that uses Parse to store profile pics.  For some reason the PFFile profile image was a pain to get working.  I finally got it working in Swift 1.2 with this function:

```
func image(completion: (image: UIImage) -> Void)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {

        if self.profilePictureImage == nil
        {
            if self.profilePicture != nil
            {

                self.fetchIfNeeded()
                if let data = self.profilePicture!.getData()
                {
                    self.profilePictureImage = UIImage(data: data)

                }
            }else
            {
                self.profilePictureImage = UIImage(named: "no_photo")!
            }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

            completion(image: self.profilePictureImage)

        })
    })
}
```

`profilePicture` is the `@NSManaged PFFile`

`profilePictureImage' is an`internal UIImage`

I've migrated the project to Swift 2.0 and it's crashing with an unwrapped nil error on the `completion` call.

What's changed?  How can I address this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First off, check out the `ParseUI` framework which includes the `PFImageView` class for automatically handling the downloading and displaying of PFFiles.

Create the outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var profilePictureImage: PFImageView!
```

Typical usage

```
// Set placeholder image
profilePictureImage.image = UIImage(named: "no_photo")

// Set remote image (PFFile)
profilePictureImage.file = profilePicture

// Once the download completes, the remote image will be displayed
profilePictureImage.loadInBackground { (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        // Log details of the failure
        println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
    } else {
        // profile picture loaded
    }
}
```

Outside of that, there have been a bunch of posts lately with people experiencing issues with `PFFile.getData()` not working in Swift2 due to the changes in iOS9 to app transport security. [According to Parse this has been fixed in the latest SDK](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/331)